# Possible to refresh entire core data objects?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I have a relatively small core data application. It contains objects that are generated using some user preferences stored in NSUserDefaults. When the user changes their preference, is it possible for all the current core data elements to be re-calculated using the updated preferences?

Comment: I would think so. Why do you think it wouldn't be possible?

Comment: When the user changes their preference, how would I change all the data that has already been stored? Is there a method that I can use to iterate through all the documents objects? (in another thread maybe). Or do I have to wipe all the data and recreate everything using the new preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just check if the user preference has changed on your delegate, then update your NSManagedObject elements.

You can use something like this to query your saved objects

```
// Query your already saved objects and change their values
- (void)changeObjects {
    NSArray *array = [CoreDataUtils fetchEntity:@"MyObject" withPredicate:nil inContext:moc];

    for (NSManagedObject *obj in array) {

        [obj setValue:@"newValue" forKey:@"columName"];
    }

    [moc save:nil];
}
```

```
+ (NSArray *)fetchEntity:(NSString *)entityName  withPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc
{
    NSFetchRequest* request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];    
    NSEntityDescription* entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError* error;

    return  [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it is exactly what I need. Ill try to implement it and accept the answer if it works. :)

Comment: If you need more help dont hesitate to ask :D

Comment: Would your code update other values that are based on "columnName"?

Comment: If you mean relationshio, yes it will